# no me funciona pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Yo quiero que se me abra la ventana de pygame pero solo me muestra
**finished in [388]ms**

a otras personas les abre la ventana de pygame, he intentado desinstalarme Python volver a instalarlo y lo mismo con pygame.

acá les muestro el código:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode()
```

Comment: tienes que especificar el `width` y `height`

Comment: @Christian comprobé lo que dices y por default el alto y ancho es el mismo que el de la pantalla. No es necesario especificar el width y height.

Comment: Esto que voy a decir es solo una hipotesis. El problema podría ser que el programa que corre tu código cierre la ventana de Pygame automáticamente cuando finaliza el script. Prueba con agregar debajo de cuando creas la ventana `while True: pass` y cuentanos que sucede si haces eso.

Comment: Lo que te propongo hará que el código se quede en un bucle infinito y el script NO finalice a menos que lo cierres desde el programa que ejecuta tu código (si es que dicho programa tiene esa opción, que supongo la tiene)

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS !!!!!

Comment: @Dante S. las respuestas no van en los comentarios. Si gustas agrégala abajo para que foncho pueda marcarla como aceptada

Comment: @BaruchSpinoza tengo miedo de que mi respuesta no sea bien recibida por ser una hipotesis. Preguntaré una segunda opinion en el chat luego.

Comment: @foncho De nada c: Me alegro de que funcionase!

Answer (score 0):

La aplicación requiere un bucle principal para mantener viva la ventana y para poder cerrar la aplicación debemos capturar el evento cuando el usuario pulse sobre el botón de cerrar que tiene ventana y de esa forma finalizar pygame correctamente.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

ventana = pygame.display.set_mode()

ventana_abierta=True

while ventana_abierta:
    for evento in pygame.event.get():
        if evento.type==pygame.QUIT:
            ventana_abierta=False

pygame.quit()
```

Voy intentar explicarte como funciona el código anterior. Para controlar la ejecución del bucle `while` declare una variable booleana llamada `ventana_abierta` y eso hará que el bucle se ejecute siempre que la ventana este abierta.

A dentro del bucle hay otro bucle `for-each` que usa la variable `evento` para almacenar una referencia al elemento de la lista que estamos recorriendo. `pygame.event.get()` es la función que permite obtener la lista de todos los eventos de la ventana, esto incluye el teclado, el ratón y otros dispositivos que estén conectados al ordenador pero el evento que nos interesa capturar es cuando el usuario pulsa el botón de cerrar que está en la esquina de la ventana.

A dentro del segundo bucle tenemos un condicional `if` que sirve para saber si el tipo de evento corresponde al botón de cerrar y en caso de ser verdadero cambiar la variable `ventana_abierta` a `False` para salir del bucle.

ahora que hemos salido del bucle debemos finalizar pygame correctamente y usamos la función `pygame.quit()` para que la ventana se cierre y todos los módulos de pygame como display, audio, event y otros también se cierren.

Comment: Por cierto, en algunas plataformas como windows es obligatorio el bucle interno que busca eventos para que la ventana no se quede congelada y el evento de cerrar ventana se maneja manualmente todo el tiempo y si no lo capturas pues no puedes cerrar la ventana.

Answer (score 0):

de esta manera es la forma mas correcta de ventana en pygame

```
import sys # libreria que se comunica con el sistema operativo
pygame.init()# inicia todo lo que haga falta para que funcione pygame
ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))# la tupla (800,600) es para darle el atamaño a la ventana

fps = 60 # cantidad de fps
clock=pg.time.Clock() # instancia del limitador de fps

while True: # no hace falta crear una variable booleana para cerrar el bucle, porque puede
traer error al finalizar pygame, por eso se captura el evento con
pygame.QUIT, para luego utilizar la función pygame.quit() que finaliza
todo lo relacionado con pygame

pygame.quit() # con esto cierras la ventana

sys.exit() # con esto le comunicas al sistema que se cierra la ejecución

pygame.display.update() #actualiza la pantalla por cada frame, sino te queda rastro de todo lo que hagas

clock.tick(fps) # esto es un limitador de frames para que no se esfuerce demas la pc

import pygame

import sys

pygame.init()

fps = 60

clock=pg.time.Clock()

while True:

    for evento in pygame.event.get():
        if evento.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(fps)
```